# VBA HTML Object Internet Explorer automation

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom, xpath

How do I select an option from a dropdown menu and update the webpage.
Code:

```
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
```

*then I navigate to a URL and I fetch the dropdown menu using html id and put value=my desired value*

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("xyz").Value = "dropdown_option"
```

I successfully get the option. But, the website doesn't update? e.g. filling up other fields.

I believe some javascript needs to be run.
How can i fix this using VBA?

Source code for dropdown menu field:

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox" class="Invalid RadComboBox RadComboBox_Telerik SearchComboBox" style="width:206px;white-space:normal;">
    <table summary="combobox" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%" class="rcbFocused rcbExpanded">
        <tbody><tr class="rcbReadOnly">
            <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$CreateWebForm_$SubjectComboBox$ComboBox" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox_Input" value="Vælg" readonly="readonly" accesskey="s" autocomplete="off"></td><td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight"><a id="ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table><input id="ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox_ClientState" name="ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
</div>

Source code for dropdown options:

    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Telerik " style="width: 204px; display: block; top: 0px; visibility: visible; transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
        <div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="height: 126px;">
    <ul class="rcbList"><li class="rcbHovered">Forespørgsel til Energinet</li>
    <li class="rcbItem">Måledata</li><li class="rcbItem">Målepunkt eller ad hoc spørgsmål</li>
    <li class="rcbItem">Orientering til alle</li>
    <li class="rcbItem">Priser</li><li class="rcbItem">Pristilknytninger</li></ul></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML content and give more details?

Comment: Break your code down and debug.  For example, does `HTMLDoc.getElementById("xyz")` return anything?

Comment: Yes @Nathan_Sav. It returns dropdown_option in the dropdown field correctly. But the webpage doesn't update.

Comment: I think dropdowns, need the selecteditem changing, without seeing the html you are trying to grab, it's difficult to advise

Comment: There are some buttons at the top, where you can change to show code format

Comment: Updated with source code, please have a look.
Can you see if there's any javascript running on basis of this dropdown field? If yes, how do I execute that script/function from my vba code?

Comment: Set your object that you are getting to be an object, from MSHTML Controls, the correct one, not just an element, then intellisense will be present, and you can see the correct methods, not just setting its `.value`  Possibly `MSHTML.HTMLSelectElement` or `MSHTML.HTMLListElement` maybe

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes, good idea. Could you please provide me a link to MSHTML library/code where I can loop up all methods. Thanks in advance!

Comment: www.google.co.uk

Comment: Is the url public? If so, please update with the url and more of your code.

Comment: no, the url is not public.

Comment: //*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[3]
This is the xpath that works with another tool.
What could be the VBA alternative to this?

Comment: HTMLDoc.querySelector("#ctl00_MainContent_CreateWebForm__SubjectComboBox_ComboBox_DropDown .rcbItem:nth-of-type(3)").click  ? Let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck with this issue. I solved this by finding **focus** property of getelementbyid method. Like this:

1. First I loop over the list to find my option. I use tagname and classname and matching the innertext property = myoption **(This is only necessary if the field doesn't allow you to input text)** Then when match occurs, perform .focus followed by .click on that object.
2. Otherwise just use focus followed by click property on the field and enter your option:

   ```
   HTMLDoc.getElementById("xyz").focus
   HTMLDoc.getElementById("xyz").click
   HTMLDoc.getElementById("xyz").Value = myoption
   ```

This will automatically refresh the html page.

This solved my issues.